# Oracle gives no table or view exists for lowercase table name

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
Insert into "user" (colums) values (?):
```

When executed with apache query runner library in java code gives error  saying no table or view exists
But when executed directly works fine.

Comment: That's not a valid String - show the code having issues.

Comment: Names in Oracle are case sensitive, and default to upper case unless quoted. Names inside double-quotes are quoted. So is the name of your table "USER" or "user"? Run `SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES WHERE UPPER(TABLE_NAME) = 'USER'` to determine this.

Comment: @BobJarvis *Nitpicking* the quotes `""` make it case senittive, by default they are not.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle double quotes `"` do *not* indicate strings, they indicate *identifiers with special chars* This implies that identifiers in double quotes are *cases sensitive*.

Oracle stores Normal identifiers in *UPPER CASE* but accepts them beeing writen im any case. Therefore your SQL works as `Insert into user (colums) values (?)` as well as `Insert into User (colums) Values (?)`.

But you may also specify identifiers with spaces or non ascii characters like `Über User Tabelle`. This works when enclosing them in double quotes:

`create table "Über User Tabelle" ("The Primary key" number);` In this case the names are also case sensitive.

So because you put your table name in double quotes Oracle looks for a lower case written table name which does not exist.

Comment: @BobJarvis thanks for pointig the spelling mistake.